# Bash String with HEX to DECIMAL

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have struggled with some similar problems already I believe discussed but really I do not get the way out: What if your file has data for example as below (hex values can be anything but fixed to 1 byte) and you want to convert each hex to decimal and keep it as in below format so instead of hex you display decimal and still comma separated? - Please note number of data lines is not fixed it can by any number.

Example 1:

```
0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51
0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a
0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0
0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51
0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a
0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0
0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51
0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a
0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0
```

Example 2: same as above but lets say it has data name in front:

```
X:0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51
Y:0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a
Z:0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0
X:0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51
Y:0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a
Z:0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0
X:0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51
Y:0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a
Z:0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0
```

So I have spent some time to understand the bash grep, sed etc.. as I am completely not Software guy I manage to play and filter out some text files in the correct format next I would like to understand how to operate on strings with more than one value and above examples will really help .
Thanks in advance.

I did try `printf`, `echo` and I am able to use them when each string in text file has one value for example :
if I use data file which has data

```
0xff
0xff
0xff
0xff
0xff
.
.
.
.
.
.
..
0xff
```

all works fine and can be converted with `printf` function:
this was found in other thread:

```bash
while read line

do

     printf '%d' $line

done < file
```

Above works great for the one hex value in line: Can this be adjusted to work with my examples or there is any better way?

Comment: You could use `sed` easily, it's just 256 different substitutions you'd have to execute to convert the file. Not the most elegant solution, but a working one. For added glitter, generate the `sed` script with a program. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use (GNU) Awk and it's `strtonum` function, which converts strings that start with `0x` to decimal numbers.

- Just splitting at `,` and starting from column `1`:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=strtonum($i); print}' file.txt
```

```
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
```

- Splitting at `,` or `:` and starting from column `2`:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=",|:"; OFS=","} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=strtonum($i); print}' file.txt
```

```
X,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
```

- This way, however, also the `:` will be converted to `,`. If this is not desired, you could print the columns `1`, `2`, and the rest separately:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=",|:"} {printf "%s:%s", $1, strtonum($2); for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) printf ",%s", strtonum($i); printf "\n"}' file.txt
```

```
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
```

Comment: Thank you - all three options are exactly what I was trying to do.
I need to test myself but i belive running awk  together with will also work for example :
 _italic_ **bold** 'cat file.txt | awk 'BEGIN {FS=",|:"} {printf "%s:%s", $1, strtonum($2); for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) printf ",%s", strtonum($i); printf "\n"}' '

Answer (score 0):

A generalized `awk` solution -

```
awk -F'[:,]' -v OFS=, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^0x/){$i=strtonum($i)}}if($1!~/^[0-9]/)sub(",",":");print}' file
```

Saved to a file, run with each of your example sets:

```
$: cat x2d
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{ FS="[:,]"; OFS="," }
{ for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { if ( $i ~ /^0x/ ) { $i=strtonum($i) } }
  if ( $1 !~ /^[0-9]/ ) sub(",",":");
  print;
}

$: ./x2d withName
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240

$: ./x2d noName
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
```

Just for the practice, the same in basic `bash`.

```
$: cat x2d
#! /bin/bash
while IFS=:, read -ra field
do for f in "${field[@]}"
   do case $f in 0x*) printf %d, $f;; *) printf %s: $f;; esac
   done
   printf $'\n'
done < $1

$: ./x2d withName
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,

$: ./x2d noName
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,
```

For data sets this small, the difference is irrelevant.
If the inputs are big, the `awk` will be faster.

Comment: One more question regarding "awk"
Can we do math operations within this function "awk -F'[:,]' -v OFS=, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^0x/){$i=strtonum($i)}}if($1!~/^[0-9]/)sub(",",":");print}' and how fast it will be ?
Can i within same function do math calculation lets say:
Each decimal value in string X:  divide by 2
Each decimal value in string Y: multiply by 2
To Each decimal value in string Z: add 2
is it possible and will this be considrable fast or slow ?
Thanks

Comment: Certainly possible, and likely faster than any shell version. How big are the files? How many are there? Make an attempt, we'll adapt it. Just be clear on the result you want.

Comment: Thanks: To be more clear-
-Lets say I am printing in shell 30 sets af data below, so there will be 30 X:, 30 Y:, 30 Z: per second in order below:
X:0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51
Y:0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a
Z:0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0
-On each value in X,Y,Z line I want to perform conversion to decimal
-On each converted valuea I want to perform math calculation ex: A string=X+ 2Y, B string=X -2Z+2X, C string=X+3Z
ABC strings has all converted values from XYZ

Comment: Above is just example as I am trying to undestand the best way to operate on the data so I can print on shell screen and read same data using Arduino and UART

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `perl`. For your first case:

```bash
$ perl -F, -lane 'print join(",", map(hex, @F))' ex1.txt
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
```

and the second, with the prefix:

```bash
$ perl -F'[:,]' -lane 'print $F[0], ":", join(",", map(hex, @F[1..$#F]))' ex2.txt
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
```

Comment: Thanks for response - in comparison which way is fastest ? perl, awk or bash ? Also please advise on my question regarding simple math on each digit ?

Comment: @GregGregory : `awk` is way ahead. And look at the complexity of `perl` :::::: ::::::: ::::::::: ::::::::: `perl -F, -lane 'print join(",", map(hex, @F))'` :::: versus the simplicity of `awk` :::: `gawk -n '$_ += ORS = RT' RS='\n|,'` ::::: `perl` has to set 4 flags , split an array, and call 3 functions, while `gawk` sets 1 flag, calls no functions and splits no arrays

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward Bash solution would be to just let Bash parse integers like it normally does. For Example 2:

```bash
to_dec() {
  local -r IFS=,:
  local -a line
  local -ai nline
  while read -ra line; do
    nline=("${line[@]:1}")
    printf '%s:%s\n' "${line[0]}" "${nline[*]}"
  done
}
```

Then `to_dec < file` gives the expected output for Example 2. A `to_dec` for Example 1 will be much simpler, because there’s no need for an auxiliary array in that case; just read the numbers:

```bash
to_dec() {
  local -r IFS=,
  local -ai nline
  while read -ra nline; do
    printf '%s\n' "${nline[*]}"
  done
}
```

As for the math operations for Example 2, requested in a comment, in pure Bash one could create functions named after the line prefixes and then execute them on the arrays. In any case, it won’t be “efficient”; it’s Bash. (Also, presumably, Bash has integer division only; to circumvent that one could use a fixed-point representation of some sort, but that’s way too hacky in Bash.)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

X() { local -n a="$1"; local -i i
      for i in "${!a[@]}"; do ((a[i] /= 2)); done; }
Y() { local -n a="$1"; local -i i
      for i in "${!a[@]}"; do ((a[i] *= 2)); done; }
Z() { local -n a="$1"; local -i i
      for i in "${!a[@]}"; do ((a[i] += 2)); done; }

to_dec() {
  local -r IFS=,:
  local -a line
  local -ai nline
  while read -ra line; do
    nline=("${line[@]:1}")
    "${line[0]}" 'nline'  # transform the array
    printf '%s:%s\n' "${line[0]}" "${nline[*]}"
  done
}

to_dec  # takes the script's default stdin / stdout
```

For a bit more efficiency and floating-point arithmetics, `awk` can help:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "[:,]" }

function X(numbers) { for (i in numbers) numbers[i] /= 2 }
function Y(numbers) { for (i in numbers) numbers[i] *= 2 }
function Z(numbers) { for (i in numbers) numbers[i] += 2 }

{
  for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) numbers[i] = strtonum($i)
  f = $1
  @f(numbers)
  output = $1 ":" numbers[2]
  for (i = 3; i <= NF; ++i) output = output "," numbers[i]
  print output
}
```

For large data processing, a proper implementation in a more low-level programming language would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your response - i have asked above the questions regarding simple math on each digit in line - please can you advise ?

Comment: @GregGregory I’ve added the arithmetics to my answer, but this looks like Bash or `awk` are not a great fit for the task if the file is e.g. gigabytes in size. Needless to say, both of my Bash and `awk` examples lack even the most rudimentary error checking.

Comment: Thank you - I am looking for integer non negative values so whole number not fractional number.
I am learning some arduino and sensors IoT DIY projects and as for arduino side it is lots of examples but then for Linux I cannot really find / maybe undestand how it works. I want to send some data between arduino and linux machine using UART and tso looking for conversion as some sensors sending HEX where I want to display as decimal and change their valuse  - Basically trying to learn how to fully control data and do manipulation on those values .

Comment: In `awk` you can always truncate it using `int(some_number)` or some such. If the Arduino sends the information in text over UART, wouldn’t it be easier to modify the code on the Arduino to send the desired format directly? If it’s sent in a binary format and printed out by some tool, then that tool could convert the numbers directly and avoid all this re-parsing and text-based manipulation.

Comment: In the scenario when Arduino sending data then yes I actually do as you mentioned - but also i am working on scenario where Linux sends data to Arduino and thought doing this conversion would be beter on source(linux in this case ) side.

Answer (score 0):

GNU AWK

```
awk -F'[,:]' -v OFS=, '
    /:/{ withName=1 }
    {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=(strtonum($i) ? strtonum($i) : $i)
    }
    withName{
        sub(/,/,":")
        withName=0
    }1
' file1 file2

81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 
'0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51
 0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a
 0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0
 0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51
 0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a
 0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0
 0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51
 0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a
 0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0' |
```

---

```
gawk -nb '$_ += ORS = RT' RS='\n|,'
```

---

```
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
```

> 

```
 gawk -nMb '$++NF = +$_' OFS='\f'
```

---

```
0x5151515151515151515151515151
                              1649317825652239364356745892811089
0x5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a
                              1832575361835821515951939880901210
0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0
                              4886867631562190709205173015736560
0x5151515151515151515151515151
                              1649317825652239364356745892811089
0x5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a
                              1832575361835821515951939880901210
0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0
                              4886867631562190709205173015736560
0x5151515151515151515151515151
                              1649317825652239364356745892811089
0x5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a5a
                              1832575361835821515951939880901210
0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0
                              4886867631562190709205173015736560
```

> 

```
echo '
X:0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51
Y:0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a 
Z:0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0 
X:0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51 
Y:0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a 
Z:0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0 
X:0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51,0x51 
Y:0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a,0x5a 
Z:0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0' |
```

---

```
gawk -nb 'NF == +(ORS = RT) || $_ += _' RS='\n?[A-Z]:|[\n,]'
```

---

```
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
X:81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81
Y:90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90
Z:240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240,240
```